# How to supplement object function from outside

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
var object = {}; //lots of stuff in here

var func = object.dosome;

object.dosome = function(a,b) {
    func(a,b);
    //someth else here i need to add 
}
```

This works but ugly.
So is there a way to supplement object.dosome method, without creating a new variable containing it's function?
Some sort of parent.dosome?

Comment: are you trying to simulate polymorphism?

Answer (score 0):

maybe create a class Object and define in its protoype the dosome() method.

```
var Object =  new function() {}; //lots of stuff in here

Object.prototype.dosome = function(a,b) {
    func(a,b);
}
//and then
var myObject = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read a little about [JS OOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). ES6 adds some nice syntactic sugar that can help you achieve what you want in fewer lines of code. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

However, if you don't want to have problems with the prototype chains, here's a simpler way of achieving what you want:

```
function chain (baseFunc, func) {
  return function () {
     var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
     args.unshift(baseFunc);
     return func.apply(this, args);
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = { 
  doSome: function (a, b) { return a + b; } 
};

obj.doSome(4, 5); // 9

obj.doSome = chain(obj.doSome, function (baseFunc, a, b) {
   var result = baseFunc(a, b);   
   return result + 10;
});

obj.doSome(4, 5); // 19
```

You can go one step further and get rid of the assignment:

```
function extend (instance, method, func) {
    instance[method] = chain(instance[method], func);
}

extend(obj, "doSome", function (baseFunc, a, b) {
    var result = baseFunc(a, b);   
    return result + 2;
});

obj.doSome(4, 5); // 21
```